# How to start a new node in Kubernetes using kops?

Tags: kubernetes, kops

We are using Kops to manage Kubernetes cluster. Cluster status are as follows:

```
Validating cluster mofang-pipeline.k8s.local

INSTANCE GROUPS
NAME            ROLE    MACHINETYPE MIN MAX SUBNETS
master-cn-northwest-1a  Master  c4.large    1   1   cn-northwest-1a
master-cn-northwest-1b  Master  c4.large    1   1   cn-northwest-1b
master-cn-northwest-1c  Master  c4.large    1   1   cn-northwest-1c
nodes           Node    r4.8xlarge  1   9   cn-northwest-1a,cn-northwest-1b,cn-northwest-1c

NODE STATUS
NAME                        ROLE    READY
ip-10-0-106-49.cn-northwest-1.compute.internal  master  True
ip-10-0-60-168.cn-northwest-1.compute.internal  master  True
ip-10-0-72-148.cn-northwest-1.compute.internal  node    True
ip-10-0-90-130.cn-northwest-1.compute.internal  master  True
ip-10-0-98-20.cn-northwest-1.compute.internal   node    True

Your cluster mofang-pipeline.k8s.local is ready
```

There are 2 nodes running now and I hope to have more of them. How can I ask Kops to start a new node in the instance group `nodes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize cluster configuration using command

```
#kops edit cluster ${CLUSTER_NAME}
```

This command opens an editor (as defined by $EDITOR) and allows you to edit the configuration. The configuration is loaded from the S3 bucket, and will be automatically updated when you save and exit the editor.

After that, you can use the below command to make it reflect on your cluster

```
#kops update cluster ${CLUSTER_NAME} --yes
```

Comment: I am a little curious about the `min` and `max` in the instance group spec. Since kops cannot dynamically start/stop instances, why not just setting a single `num` field to specify how many instance I want ?

Comment: @ DaTong min is the minimum number of instance which should be always running, and max is the maximum number of instance kubernetes can launch.

Comment: Yes, I can understand the literal meaning of the two fields. But if min is 1, max is 9, current is 2, how can I have 9 running nodes, without modifying the configuration? Actually I tried Cluster Autoscaler to achieve that dynamically. I thought kops could be able to do that. Well, anyway, I would mark your reply as answer.